# What is the correct syntax of sum range with variable rows and columns - Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel vba :

What is the correct syntax of sum range with variable rows and columns? As in, `=sum(cells(var1row,var1col), cells(var2row,var2col))`.

Requirement is that I need to find the sum of a dynamic range where both rows and columns of the start and end cells will change after each cycle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37308927/2727437

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will work

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1)))
```

You will have to change the numbers "1,1" and "5,1" to suit your dynamic ranges.